# What are the attributes which allow you to restrict access to your DLLs?

Tags: c#, security, .net-4.0, attributes, assemblies

I remember reading briefly that you can add assembly attributes so that you can only allow specific assemblies to call into an assembly. But I can't remember where I saw that or how to do it - can someone point me in the right direction?

Just to be clear, this question is asking:

1. I have assembly A and assembly B.
2. Assembly B needs to access some member(s) within assembly A.
3. Both assemblies will be sent to others in the form of a software product.
4. I only want assembly B to be able to see the members in assembly A.
5. Anyone who needs to use something in assembly A will have to do so via assembly B. Assembly A's members are all hidden/internal so 3rd parties can not see them.

Comment: Which framework version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [InternalsVisibleTo Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to allow assemblies referencing your assembly to see classes and members marked as `internal`. I believe there is no way to prevent an assembly to reference your assembly and access all `public` classes and members.

Note: using reflection, any assembly can access any class or member, regardless of whether that is `public` or `internal` (or `private`), provided the application is running with Full Trust (which is usually the case).

Comment: This is what I need. I want public members to be public but internals to span assemblies. I'll give it a try now.

Answer (score 1):

[Friend Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx) are what you're looking for:

> A friend assembly is an assembly that
>   can access another assembly's Friend
>   (Visual Basic) or internal (C#) types
>   and members. If you identify an
>   assembly as a friend assembly, you no
>   longer have to mark types and members
>   as public in order for them to be
>   accessed by other assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such assembly attributes, there is only one assembly attribute related to the type visibility which grants access to assembly internals by other assemblies - [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

Comment: This is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any attribute you could be set to restrict access.

I used this link as a reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s(v=vs.71).aspx

For the DLL code itself, try using internal to mark items that only the assembly can access.  For items truly accessible to the outside world, mark as public.

Comment: Yep - I think my question was unclear, I'll update it since @dtb's answer is exactly what I was looking for.